# How to find current url in any Shopify Liquid file (page.url and request.url not working)

Tags: liquid, shopify-template, liquid-template, shopify-liquid

We are injecting a modal in our site, which is being build using Shopify liquid templates. And we want to change the css of that modal according to the url change.
I have tried **window global** object but it is not working as it involve server side rendering.
also **page.url** and **request.url** global liquid object didn't worked for me.

Liquid file structure

[image: Liquid file structure]

I am new to Shopify liquid template, Please help me here.
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `case` statement and change your CSS based on the page handle:

```
{% case page.handle %}
   {% when 'page-handle-one' %}
      do something...
   {% when 'page-handle-two' %}
      do something else...
   {% else %}
{% endcase %}
```